# Different methods of displaying camera under SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, shadow

I'm developing a `AR` Application which can use few different engines. One of them is based on `SceneKit` (not `ARKit`).

I used to make `SceneView` background transparent, and just display `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` under it. But this have created a problem later - turns out, that if you use clear `backgroundColor` for `SceneView`, and then add a `floor node` to it, which has `diffuse.contents = UIColor.clear` (transparent floor), then shadows are not displaying on it. And the goal for now is to have shadows in this engine.

I think the best method of getting shadows to work is to set camera preview as `SCNScene.background.contents`. For this I tried using `AVCaptureDevice.default(for: video)`. This worked, but it has one issue - you can't use video format that you want - `SceneKit` automatically changes format when it's assigned. I even asked Apple for help using one of two help requests you can send to them, but they replied, that for now there is no public api that would allow me to use this with the format I would like. And on `iPhone 6s` this format changes to `30 FPS`, and I need it to be `60 FPS`. So this option is no good.

Is there some other way I would assign camera preview to scene background property? From what I read I can use also `CALayer` for this property, so I tried assigning `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, but this resulted in black color only, and no video. I have updated frame of layer to correct size, but this didn't work anyway. Maybe I did something wrong, and there is a way to use this `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` or something else?

Can you suggest some possible solutions? I know I could use `ARKit`, and I do for other engine, but for this particular one I need to keep using `SceneKit`.